# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\glasanje\index.php on line 111

Tags: php

```
<?php

    foreach (iscupaj_viceve() as $id => $glasanje){

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vicevi WHERE id = $id");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo    "<h2><center>".$row['Title']."</h2>";
            echo    "<div id='linkovi1'>" .nl2br($row["VicText"]). "<br></div>";
        }
?>
    <p>

            <a href="?glasanje=gore&id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="../images/plus_sign.png" width="29" height="29"></a>
            <a href="?glasanje=dolje&id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="../images/minus_sign.png" width="29" height="29"></a>
        Ukupno glasova : [
        <?php
            include 'core/db/connect.php';
            // Check connection
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT glasanje FROM vicevi WHERE id = $id");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            echo nl2br($row['glasanje']);
            }
        ?>]
    </p>
<?php

    }

?>
```

And this is my function

```
function iscupaj_viceve(){


$sql = "SELECT id, VicText, glasanje FROM vicevi ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10";

$rezultati = mysql_query($sql);
$glasanje = array();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezultati)) !== false){
    $rezultati[$row['id']] = $row['VicText'];
}
return $rezultati;
```

}

Browser prints this error message:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\glasanje\index.php on line 111

But i can't seem to find a way to solve this problem :S Help?

Comment: I Think you have your function messed up. I do not see `$glasanje = array();` being used after it is set

Comment: Marko, Please update your question with code. I wont sit through and format the code you have posted in the text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is overwriting `$rezultati`. I would suggest rewriting it as:

```
function iscupaj_viceve() {

    $rows = array();

    $sql = "SELECT id, VicText, glasanje FROM vicevi ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10";

    $rezultati = mysql_query($sql);

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezultati)) !== false) {
        $rows[$row['id']] = $row['VicText'];
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `$glasanje = array();` useless?

Comment: Because the return is outside of the whileloop, set to return `$rows;`  wouldn't it return only the last param stepped through that while loop? Shouldn't you append it to  `$glasanje[] = array ($rows);`
then return it?

Comment: Daryl Gill, so long as `$row['id']` is unique on each iteration, all rows will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

iscupaj_viceve() doesn't always return an array.

```
$glasanje = array();
```

should be

```
$rezultati = array();
```